# moderncv in AUCTeX doesn't produce accented vowel, why?

Tags: moderncv, emacs, font-encodings

I'm trying to write a resumé with the `moderncv` class in AUCTEX (special LaTeX mode in *emacs*). I actually wrote the *.tex file in TeXmaker months ago then recently tried to re-ran the file with AUCTEX.

Emacs prompted me to choose b/w XeTeX and LuaTeX and whether I wanted to remember the choice. I chose XeTeX (no special reason) and later discovered that LuaTeX gives out compilation errors about `à` (I'm writing in Italian, so accented vowels are a must). XeTeX compiles the pdf but doesn't render 'à' (accented a) every time it occurs.

Here's a short example. In the picture below I've underlined the missing spot of 'à'. Plus, now that I'm noticing it, in the tex file there appears to be a `\340` in place of the `à` character.

I suppose that it's a package that I haven't loaded or some LaTeX engine configuration or even a wrong encoding?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper, sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}
\moderncvicons{awesome}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{wasysym}

\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\firstname{Maria}
\familyname{Rossi}
\mobile{+39\,444\,552\,44\,00}
\email{maria.rossi@tiscali.it}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{0.20\textwidth}

\usepackage[unicode,pdfencoding=auto]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Informazioni Personali}
\cvline{Nome}{Maria}
\cvline{Cognome}{Rossi}
\cvline{Cittadinanza}{Italiana}
\cvline{Residenza}{Roma}

\section{Abilità linguistiche}
\cvitemwithcomment{Italiano}{Madrelingua}{}
\cvitemwithcomment{Inglese}{Ottimo}{}
\cvitemwithcomment{Francese}{Base}{}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: impossible to say what's wrong but you should not use inputenc or fontenc packages with xelatex/lualatex. Most likely your file is not in UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: I get some errors about fontawesome but if I comment out fontenc and inputenc then the accented a appear correctly.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't solve the problem. Notice the 'echo' area of emacs -- how do I change the encoding? What should I choose from the list of available enconding?

Comment: `C-x <ret> f` is one way, then save as utf-8 when prompted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file appears to be saved in an incorrect encoding.

You can use `C-x <ret> f` and answer UTF-8 to the prompt to save the file in UTF-8.

Also do not use the `inputenc` and `fontenc` packages with xetex or luatex.

Comment: I did as you suggested, however if I 'clean' the compilation files then close and reopen the *.tex I get again some incorrect encoding. Basically I have to adjust the encoding every time I open the file. Is there a way to set it right once and for all? Not that I mind checking for proper encoding. Also, this happens only for this file -- other *.tex files I created in AUCTEX don't give me this problem. (Just a minor glitch I _can_ live with)

Comment: `M-x add-file-local-variable RET coding RET utf-8 RET`.